# Scrapy: ascii' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapinghub

I am having problem on running my crawler

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
```

I am using this code

```
author = str(info.css(".author::text").extract_first())
```

but still I am having that error any idea how can solve it?
Thank you!

Here's the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 
 102, in iter_errback
yield next(it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh_scrapy/middlewares.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
for x in result:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
for x in result:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
  return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
 File "/app/__main__.egg/teslamotorsclub_spider/spiders/teslamotorsclub.py", line 40, in parse
author = str(info.css(".author::text").extract_first())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Post the full error message, including traceback

Comment: Alrigh done @wjandrea

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
author = info.css(".author::text").extract_first().decode('utf-8')
```

The reason for this is extract_first returns a raw bytes object. To convert this to a string, python makes no guesses as to how it's encoded, therefore, you need to make that explicit. Utf-8 will handle just about anything you throw at it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but still I got the error return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Post your entire script and I'll be able to help further